# If I have a game level that needs precision and fast decision making, what skills are being challenged?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases

What should I put in the empty space? "Challenge your ___ skills..."? "precision skills"? Just "precision"? Maybe something else? Thank you!

I am talking about a scenarion in a 3D game where your character is on platforms high up in the sky that are quite narrow and require precision to move around and not fall, where you have to turn often and make fast decisions.

Comment: Thanks man, I looked at them but it's not quite what I was looking for. I was thinking more like a 3D game where your character is on platforms high up in the sky that are quite narrow and require precision to move around and not fall, where you have to turn often and make fast decisions.

Comment: You've already described the game as challenging your *precision and fast decision making*. So, why are you rejecting that?

Comment: Try “***skillz***”  Colloquially meaning “proficiency at a video game”. ( among other things).  As in “I just got passed level 600. “ “You gots mad skillz, bro.”

Comment: I think *agility* covers the physical precision aspect pretty well, including the rapid turns. You could say "Challenger your physical and mental agility."

Comment: Sounds like "twitch" gaming to me.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a dota background, if you're looking for the ability to precisely control your input devices (keyboard, mouse, VR, etc.), the word is **mechanical skills**.

I've also witnessed the word used in contexts other than strategy games, for example, in this text: https://www.quora.com/Which-video-game-requires-the-most-mechanical-skill

Note that mechanical skills do not include decision making, so if I were to write that sentence, it would be:

> Put your decision making and mechanical skills to test.

From a non-gaming perspective, and if you want to keep the sentence structure the same, **reflex**, which can be used an adjective, meaning pertaining to timely decisions performed as a response to a stimulus and without conscious thought, and depending on the type of game, it may also test **perception**, which is the ability to become aware of something through the senses.

> Challenge your reflex skills.

> Challenge your perception skills.

I'd still go with *"Put your decision making and mechanical skills to test."*

Answer (score 0):

Perspicuity perhaps?

Perspicuity is defined as: 
     a. clearness or lucidity, as of a statement.
     b.the quality of being perspicuous.

And Perspicuous is defined as:
     a.clearly expressed or presented; lucid.
     b. perspicacious.

Finally, Perspicacious is defined as:
     a. having keen mental perception and understanding;discerning:
     b. to exhibit perspicacious judgment.
     c. Archaic. having keen vision.

Comment: Would you please add the references you used for these definitions.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perspicuity
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perspicuous
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perspicacious

Comment: Thank you, I've incorporated them into your original answer.

Comment: Very much appreciated! I'll re-read the guidelines before posting elsewhere in this forum.